# C# .NET MVC - Internet Explorer doesn't run controller method

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, caching

usually I code for Mozilla Firefox/Chrome. My client reported a bug when working on Internet Explorer. I checked it and he was right. I noticed that Internet Explorer doesn't run my controller method, it just shows me its view without doing thing in controller method. It causes a problem, because I have session clearing when going into my "Create" method. On Mozilla/Chrome it works as expected - controller method is invoked. How to prevent that behavior? It is connected somehow with caching? I tried to add `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]` on whole controller for testing (as I found on the internet) but it didn't work.

Comment: can you provide some code so that we know what youre doing and can look to replicate this please

Comment: Imo it doesn't matter, I just put breakpoint at the beginning of my Create method, Mozilla/Chrome runs it, IE not.

Comment: You could try Developper Tools in IE to see what is sending to the server in each request.

Comment: you can also put some logging in controller method to debug the things in better way.

Comment: Have to considered you have invalid HTML or javascript that's just not working in IE. I seriously doubt a controller method "doesn't run" specifically for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I helped myself.

I added an annotation on whole controller:

`[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]`

I also had to remove old cache from IE.